# How to Bind data to multi select?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I have an editable form which contains a multi select field with an object array that I need to populate with previous data as selected in that array.

```js
this.EditSplitConfigForm.patchValue({
    cecadtEventTypes: editSplitConfigModal.cecadtEventTypes
});
```

```html
 <select class=" form-control dropdown-primary"  formControlName="cecadtEventTypes" multiple>
    <option>--select--</option>
    <option>All</option>
    <option *ngFor="let adtEvent of adtEventList" [ngValue]="adtEvent.id">
        {{adtEvent.adtEvent}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to patch with value array.
Please have a look on this [demo url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqceyu)
here is the sample code.

```
form: FormGroup;
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
        this.form = fb.group({
            cecadtEventTypes: []
        })  
    }

    changeSelection(): void {
        this.form.patchValue({
            cecadtEventTypes: [1,2,3]
        })
    }

    // html
    <form [formGroup]="form">
        <select formControlName="cecadtEventTypes" multiple="multiple" style="height: 120px;width: 20%">
            <option>--select--</option>
            <option>All</option>
            <option *ngFor="let item of adtEventList" [ngValue]="item.id">{{ item.adtEvent }}</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <button type="button" (click)="changeSelection()">Change</button>
```

Comment: Yes that's what i'm doing.  
this.EditSplitConfigForm.patchValue({
    cecadtEventTypes: editSplitConfigModal.cecadtEventTypes
});
Here editSplitConfigModal.cecadtEventTypes returns an array

Comment: an value array? I mean [1,2,3,4] like this?

Comment: Thanks bro its working ..I was sending a string of array but it was expctng integer array.

Answer (score 1):

use ngx-mat-select-search :
the example of how to use:
https://stackblitz.com/github/bithost-gmbh/ngx-mat-select-search-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html